# sprintf for sql query with line breaks in rstudio

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, string, printf

I have the following (extraordinarily long) sql query:

```
select distinct m.*
FROM
(
select c.geo as zipcode, 
a.startdate, 
a.data -> 'Tmin' as Tmin,
a.data -> 'Tmax' as Tmax,
a.data -> 'Tavg' -> as Tavg,
a.data -> 'StnPressure' as StnPressure,
a.data -> 'SeaLevel' as SeaLevel ,
ST_DISTANCE(b.geo, c.geo) as distanceS,
RANK() over (partition by c.geo, a.startdate order by ST_DISTANCE(b.geo, c.geo)) as rnkS
from facttable a
inner join shapefile b on (a.shape_id=b.shape_id)
inner join shapefile c on (ST_DWithin(b.geo,c.geo,5000))
where data_id=98765 and 
b.id = '1000' and 
c.id = '2000' and
c.geoid = '12345'
) m
where m.rnkS = 1
```

I am trying to port this to R and keep it formatted nicely in my r script as well as update the query with R variables using the following syntax:

```
query = sprintf("select distinct m.*
FROM
(
select c.geo as zipcode, 
a.startdate, 
a.data -> 'Tmin' as Tmin,
a.data -> 'Tmax' as Tmax,
a.data -> 'Tavg' -> as Tavg,
a.data -> 'StnPressure' as StnPressure,
a.data -> 'SeaLevel' as SeaLevel ,
ST_DISTANCE(b.geo, c.geo) as distanceS,
RANK() over (partition by c.geo, a.startdate order by ST_DISTANCE(b.geo, c.geo)) as rnkS
from facttable a
inner join shapefile b on (a.shape_id=b.shape_id)
inner join shapefile c on (ST_DWithin(b.geo,c.geo,(%s)))
where data_id=(%s) and 
b.id = (%s) and 
c.id = (%s) and
c.geoid = (%s)
) m
where m.rnkS = 1", var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5)
```

But the sprintf function in RStudio includes formatting characters and tabs such that when I query the database, the query never returns. When I remove all the breaks and tabs manually, query works.

Is there a way I can keep this long query formatted in my r script and pass it to sprintf without needing to remove all the line breaks and tabs so that the query still works when I send it to the database?

Thank you

Comment: First `sprintf` does not parameterize queries. You are still interpolating values to SQL. Second, what errors are you receiving? R's `\n`, `\t`, etc. should have no affect on query processing. Please also tag your RDBMS, so we know your SQL dialect.

Comment: Using `RODBC` on MySQL, I don't receive errors when running a query which includes the tab or newline characters that `sprintf` generates. I suspect it's your connection or method. In addition to what Parfait asks, what package and command are you using to run the query?

Comment: Thanks, I'm connecting to an MSSQL database using JDBC driver and RJDBC package.  Command is `dbGetQuery`. Error is that it never returns.